# Java, changing active card for another class

Tags: java, swing

Looking at other answers, i have followed exactly what they say, but i just keep getting the nullPointerException error. I have 4 classes, the 2 below, a GUI class and main menu class. Main manages the card layout and i would like a button in the Insert class to change the "Active" card to main menu class.

Main:

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ChooserListener{
    MainMenu mm;
    Insert InsertCustomer;  
    public JPanel mPanel;    
    CardLayout cl;  

    private String c;

        public Main(){
            super();

            //add mPanel, set to CardLayout and add the Main
            mPanel = new JPanel();
            this.add(mPanel);
            cl = new CardLayout();
            mPanel.setLayout(cl);
            //add classes
            mm = new MainMenu(this);        
            InsertCustomer = new Insert();           
            //add classes to mPanel
            mPanel.add(mm, "mm");
            mPanel.add(InsertCustomer, "InsertCustomer");
        }

        public void tell(Object o) {
            c = o.toString();
            cl.show(mPanel, c);
        }

        public void swapView(String key) {
           CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mPanel.getLayout());
           cl.show(mPanel, key);
        }
    }
```

Insert:

```
public class Insert extends JPanel{   

   private JButton logoutbutton;
   private LogoutListener lListener;

   public Insert() {
      super();

      //BUTTONS
        //logout button
      JButton logoutbutton = new JButton("Main Menu");
      this.add(logoutbutton);
      lListener = new LogoutListener(null);
      logoutbutton.addActionListener(lListener);
   }

   private class LogoutListener implements ActionListener{
       private Main main;

       public LogoutListener(Main main){
           this.main = main;
       }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           main.swapView("mm");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the stackTrace here ?

Comment: Where do you have NullPointerException?

Comment: A very straightforward null pointer exception.  This question is unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
lListener = new LogoutListener(null);
```

Your LogoutListener takes your Main-class, but you give him null. Of course you will get a NullPointerException (at least on your logoutButton-click).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in next lines :

```
lListener = new LogoutListener(null);

main.swapView("mm");
```

You need to put reference to your `Main` class, not `null` as you done. Because of your `main` in `LogoutListener` is null and you catch `NPE`.

Simple solution is to transfer reference of your `Main` to `Insert` with help of constructor and then transfer that to `LogoutListener`.